# Get line numbers of words present in a file

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, numbers, line

I have two files:

File 1:

```
military  troop deployment number need
```

File 2 :

```
foreign 1242
military 23020
firing  03848
troop 2939
number 0032
dog 1234
cat 12030
need w1212
```

I want to read the line from file 1 and print those words and the line number they are in file2.

My output should be like:

```
military 2, troop 4, deployment <does not exist>, number 5, need 8
```

I tried the code:

```
words= 'military  troop  deployment  number  need'
sent = words.split()
print sent

with open("file2","r") as f1:
    for line_num,line in enumerate(f1):
        if any([word in line for word in sent]):
             print line_num, line
```

This is printing all the lines in which these words are. In addition to that it is also printing words like pre-military, needlessly,.. etc. I just need those exact words and their line numbers. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the wrong thing. You want to print the word not the whole line. Also if you use `any`, you do not know which word matched.

Here are 2 approaches. The first does not detect empty entries.

```
words= 'military  troop  deployment  number  need'
sent = words.split()

matched = []
with open("file2","r") as f1:
    for i, line in enumerate(f1):
        for word in sent:
            if word in line:
                matched.append('%s %d' % (word, i + 1))

print ', '.join(matched)
```

**Output:**

```
military 2, troop 4, number 5, need 8
```

---

If you want to print the empty entries as well.

```
words= 'military  troop  deployment  number  need'
sent = words.split()

linenos = {}

with open("file2","r") as f1:
    for i, line in enumerate(f1):
        for word in sent:
            if word in line:
                linenos[word] = i + 1

matched2 = []
for word in sent:
    if word in linenos:
        matched2.append('%s %d' % (word, linenos[word]))
    else:
        matched2.append('%s <does not exist>' % word)
print ', '.join(matched2)
```

**Output:**

```
military 2, troop 4, deployment <does not exist>, number 5, need 8
```

**To handle multiple occurrences of a word and print only the first line.**

```
words= 'military  troop  deployment  number  need'
sent = words.split()
linenos = {}

with open("file2", "r") as f1:
    for i, line in enumerate(f1):
        for word in sent:
            if word in line:
                if word in linenos:
                    linenos[word].append(i + 1)
                else:
                    linenos[word] = [i + 1]

matched2 = []
for word in sent:
    if word in linenos:
        matched2.append('%s %r' % (word, linenos[word][0]))
    else:
        matched2.append('%s <does not exist>' % word)

print ', '.join(matched2)
```

Output same as previous example.

Comment: It helps a lot. Thank you so much :) And, what if I just want it to print the earliest of the line numbers. Like if military occurs at 10 places. What if I just want the first place's line number?

Comment: Maybe the dict could hold a list of all the line numbers a word occurs on. Then if you only want the first you just use the 0th element of the list.

Comment: Ok. I will try. If possible and if you could add in that line of code as well it would be great. I am just learning. No stress though :)